# Searching an Angular2 visual form editor or a form engine with the possibility to generate forms by GUI or generator or centralised config?

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, typescript

we are working on a couple of Angular2< projects in our development group. While the other developers getting used to code even bigger forms directly with Typescript and HTML mark-up within our Angular 2< projects, I'm not very happy with this approach.

Now we are starting some new projects what require bigger form structures even with conditional logic and this projects may grow over the next few years. I guess coding it directly with Typescript/Html (even with split components and services) will end up in a lot of redundant code where every form change or extension will be a pain in the ass in the future.

Are there any visual editors for forms with AngularJS 2 support or form engines what allow complex form structures with some kind of GUI or generator or centralised config?

I just want to create complex form structures in Angular2< without senseless coding overhead.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I have built an angular application recently and the form contains more than 50 fields. What I suggest is breaking it down to small pieces, pass the `form` instance into children components. For instance, split two main parts are `basic information` and `social media` create their own components and put them into their own, once there's any updates(add or remove), use `@Input` and `@Output()` decorators pass them back to parent component, parent component would update the changes locally and remotely(via HttpClient).

```
 form = this.fb.group({
    basic: this.fb.group({
      name: '',
      description: ''
    }),
    social_media: this.fb.array([
      this.createSocialMedia({ sm_id: 1, sm_name: 'facebook' }),
      this.createSocialMedia({ sm_id: 3, sm_name: 'instagram' }),
    ])
  })
```

parent templates:

```
 <div>
      <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <app-basic
          [parent]="form">
        </app-basic>
        <app-social-media
          [parent]="form"
          [media]="social_media"
          (added)="addSocialMedia($event)">
        </app-social-media>
     </form>
```

child `basic` component template:

```
   <div [formGroup]="parent">
      <div formGroupName="basic">
        <input 
          type="text" 
          placeholder="Name"
          formControlName="name">
        <input 
          type="text" 
          placeholder="Description"
          formControlName="description">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Now, if you want to add one more feature, let's say `billing information` what you need do is add 
`billing: this.fb.group({...//billing details})` into your existing `form`, render `<app-billing></app-billing>` in parent template and then build the template for billing itself.